# Securly uploading videos in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, video

This question is about letting a potentially malicious user upload videos to your site - specifically, handling the file itself.

With images, one one simple thing you do (after every other thing is validated) is

```
    if( $uploaded_type == 'image/jpeg' ) {
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $uploaded_tmp );
        imagejpeg( $img, $temp_file, $imageQualityPercentage);
    }
    elseif( $uploaded_type == 'image/png') {
        $img = imagecreatefrompng( $uploaded_tmp );
        imagesavealpha($img, TRUE);
        imagepng( $img, $temp_file, 9*(1-$imageQualityPercentage/100));
    }
```

Which basically re-creates the image from user input.

Is there an equivalent in PHP for videos? I'd very much like if mp4/oog/webm ones existed (and supported most codecs), but anyone knows any open source libraries that do this for at least any format/codec?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ffmpeg or like to extract images and audio and later stitch them together, but I guess there also you must take some security consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I probably could, in the end I'd need to literally re-implement the video encoder/decoder for each format, which would take more time by a few orders of magnitude than what I have.

Answer (score 0):

by using .htaccess secure video folder at your server.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ mycontroller.php?h=$1&t=$2&v=$3
RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.(mkv|mp4)$-[F]
```

Comment: This answer is why I asked this question in the security forum rather than SO before that amazing contributor migrated it.  
No, ensuring the file **name** is of the correct format is not "securing" the input, and it has also nothing to do with what I specifically asked.